# Can't show placeholder in select2.js after selection

Tags: jquery-select2

Using select2.js to retrieve remote data bound to a hidden input.

```
 <input type="hidden" id="departmentNameEntry"  style="width:300px"/>
```

I have set the placeholder in the initialization:

```
$("#departmentNameEntry").select2({
        placeholder: "Search for a department",
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        ajax: {
            url: "Handlers/DeptNameSearch_handler.ashx",
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    departmentNameFragment: term // search term entered into querystring for handler
                };
            },
            results: function (data, page) { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                return { results: data };
            }
        },
        formatResult: function (item) {
            return item.text;
        },
        formatSelection: formatDepartmentNames,
        formatNoMatches: function (term) {
            return 'no department name matches your query';
        }
    });
```

But as soon as an item is selected, the placeholder goes blank. How can I reset it to the original string?  I have tried placing the init code in a separate function and execing it again, but no joy.  Other questions I have seen answered seem to be specific to binding to a SELECT.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  The placeholder is supposed to go blank and the selected value should be entered instead.  It's only a placeholder.

Comment: @basher:  When the page is first loaded, the user can see the control with the placeholder "Search for a Department", so he knows what to do next.  But if the user hits escape, or otherwise clears the controls on the page to start the search operation over, the placeholder is blank, and his instructions disappear.  Yes, I can put a label above the control that says "Search for a Department", but I thought I would use the placeholder for that, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't RTFM closely enough.

The formatSelection option requires you to return a string that is then displayed in the select2 in place of the placeholder text.  Here is my function:

```
function formatDepartmentNames(dept) {
    $('#hfDepartmentID').val(dept.id);   // when user has selected from the list, put id in an input
    $('#hfDepartmentName').val(dept.text); // stash the dept name for later
    DepartmentCurrentBossesGet(dept.id, dept.text);  // call another function
    DepartmentBossHistoryGet(dept.id);  // call yet another function
    $('.row4').show();  // show useful data on the page
    return dept.text;   // return the dept name so select2 can display it
}
```

Hopes this helps someone.